# Access element and Loop through in php

Tags: php, arrays, object

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [EXPORT-RECORDS] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [PRODUCT] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [PRODUCTS_NAME] => Panasonic Super Heavy Duty Battery AA - 4 Pack
                            [PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION] => Batteries keep going and going and going until they don\'t. And there\'s nothing more disappointing than 

                        )

                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [PRODUCTS_NAME] => Panasonic Super Heavy Duty Battery AA - 4 Pack
                            [PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION] => Batteries keep going and going and going until they don\'t. And there\'s nothing more disappointing than
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

This is what i have in `print_r($xml);` how do i loop through [0],[1] and access its elements. I need `[PRODUCTS_NAME]` of each individual product. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$xml = <<<XML

<EXPORT-RECORDS>
        <PRODUCT>
            <PRODUCTS_NAME>Panasonic Super Heavy Duty Battery AA - 4 Pack</PRODUCTS_NAME>
            <PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION>Batteries keep going and going and going until they don\'t. And there\'s nothing more disappointing than </PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION>
        </PRODUCT>
        <PRODUCT>
            <PRODUCTS_NAME>Panasonic Super Heavy Duty Battery AA - 4 Pack</PRODUCTS_NAME>
            <PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION>Batteries keep going and going and going until they don\'t. And there\'s nothing more disappointing than</PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION>
        </PRODUCT>
</EXPORT-RECORDS>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach($xml->PRODUCT as $PRODUCT){
    echo $PRODUCT->PRODUCTS_NAME;
}
```

https://ideone.com/19AMTL

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($SimpleXMLElement['EXPORT-RECORDS']['PRODUCT'] as $Key => $Dataset){
    /* Do whatever you want with $Key and $Dataset */
}
```

That loop should do it. As an example,

```
echo $Dataset['PRODUCTS_NAME'];
```

would, placed in the body of the Loop, echo all product names.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that `$Dataset` (oh, I don't like Capitalized variables, nevermind :P) is instance of `SimpleXMLElement` class.